# Transferring C: directories to another drive

Tags: partitioning, windows-11, redirection

I've recently been preoccupied in transferring frequently updated directories in C: — this, C:\ProgramData, C:\Temp & C:\Users, to another drive whose physical storage is more adept at being updated (the idea that HDDs can still take more rewrites than flash-based storage). Transferring them also makes it easier to do a clean re-install of Windows should the need arises.

My procedure to doing this is quite simple. Boot into a Windows installation media to do an install. Just after the files are copied & before the first reboot, shutdown the computer. Then I boot into a recovery software or what have you & move aforementioned directories to the other drive, say D:, & junction linking (mklink /J) the abovementioned directories to where they've been relocated — D:\PerfLogs, D:\ProgramData, D:\Temp & D:\Users. Then I let the installation boot freely & deploy everything.

What the worst that can come of this? I mean, I am junction linking all the references & third party software shouldn't be able to tell. On that note, internally to Microsoft, what problems might arise?

Comment: What about reinstalling the OS? Windows always demands it has a partition all for itself during install.

Comment: I have done that - no issues.

Comment: No issues where? Moving/junction linking or reinstalling Windows?

Comment: No.  Like I posted, heavy use does not bother or hurt the SSD

Comment: *the idea that HDDs can still take more rewrites than flash-based storage* A very wrong idea that many long term studies have disproved beyond any reasonable doubt.

Comment: I've been somewhat careful with SSDs that I once considered having a Linux distro/custom setup that uses a partition backended with RAM (a ramdisk). During boot, this ramdisk is populated with data & during shutdown, it flushes everything to the real files.

Answer (score 2):

It will be slower and in my view unnecessary.  A good SSD drive will outlast the computer and be faster in the bargain.

You are ill advised to move all of USERS - Much of Appdata is better on drive C and some of Appdata cannot reliably be moved.

I have a 6 year old ThinkPad X1 with top quality fast SSD and it is good for 600 TBW . After 6 years of heavy use including virtual machines it has less that 100 TBW so far